# Restore Pixel C backup

Tags: backup, google-drive, google-backup

I had a Pixel C, which I backuped (System -> Backup -> ...). I can see that backup (**1**) in Google Drive.
After the Pixel C died I now have a new Pixel C and would like to restore that Backup (**1**).
When setting up the device, it gave me no option to restore from the previous Backup (**1**). So I enabled backing up the new device and now have a second Backup (**2**) in Google Drive.

Now my question is - how do I restore the previous Backup (**1**)?

Comment: Related: [Google Backup: Multiple devices using the same account - what happens on Restore?](/q/42245/16575) – especially check [lapis' answer](/a/87808/16575), which seems to match your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and Google support pointed me to this [link](https://support.google.com/pixel/answer/6328687?hl=en).
There is a section on restoring from backup, which references Nexus devices but apparently works for the Pixel tablets as well.